Bug in some IDE's when handling repeating linear gradients
I recently encountered a bizarre bug when using the repeating-linear-gradient CSS property in IDEs - codepen and live server (VSC.) They render the gradients incorrectly, rotating small segments of the lines instead of the entire line. It only rendered correctly in Mozilla's live examples and when the code is injected into a page. (this was tested in firefox and edge)
Here's the simple gradient I tried:
body {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    background: repeating-linear-gradient(179deg, #000000, #000000 13px, #ffffff 13px, #ffffff 65px);
  }

Here's the expected result:
Zebra stripe gradient at a 45 degree angle
And here's the result I got:
Whatever this is

Set height: 100vh for body and you'll see that nothing is broken (aside from CSS itself).
